# How to check if the collection view cell is clicked

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I want to check if the collectionview cell is clicked

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
  didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //code..
  }
```

Comment: What's the question? That method is called when the cell is clicked, and it hands you the `indexPath`, so you _are_ checking.

Comment: The method you posted is called when the cell is clicked. In `UICollectionViewCell`, there are a couple of booleans you may be interested in: 1) `isSelected` and 2) `isHighlighted`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you already have the key to your problem, it's just you don't know how to use it.

So every UIKit element has it's own delegate which is called when some event occurs.
In case of collection view, whenever cells are clicked `didSelectItemAt` will be called.

Here is an example

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
  didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Cell \(indexPath.row + 1) clicked")
  }
```

Considering above code just imagine you have 5 cells,
Whenever you click on any cell the above code will execute.

If you click on Third cell it will print: `Cell 3 clicked`

And if you don't click any cell nothing will happen.

Hope now everything is clear,  **Happy coding :)**

Comment: If your issue was resolved you can mark this as answer